# Codenameone: Short Weekdays cannot be localised in a Picker with Type DateTime

Tags: codenameone

I'm not able to localise the short Weekdays in a Picker with type DateTime which uses the lighweight-Component.

In the ResourceBundle I added the translations for Short-Month and Short-Weekday:

```
MONTH_SHORTNAME_JANUARY
etc.
```

resp.

```
WEEKDAY_SHORTNAME_MONDAY
etc.
```

The short monthnames are used in the Picker with the Simulator - the short weekdays not. On an iPad neither the short monthnames nor the short weekdays are used. On an Android-Device it looks like in the Simulator.

I think the reason is, that the instance of SimpleDateFormat, which is created in the DateModelAdapter in Spinner3D, does not set the resourceBundle in its instance of DateFormatSymbols. Therefore the translations I added are not used.

I attached 2 Screenshots: First a Screenshot from the iPad - second a Screenshot from the Simulator.

[image: Screenshot from the iPad]
[image: Screenshot from the Simulator]

Am I right or do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Try the resource bundle strings: `Calendar.Sun`, `Calendar.Mon` etc...

From looking at the code I think those should work.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. The bundle strings Calendar.Sun ... are used in the DateTimeRenderer which is used by DateTimeSpinner - but not by DateTimeSpinner3D. And DateTimeSpinner3D is used by the lightweight Picker for type DateTime.

Comment: OK. Take a look at this: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2773
It's for the old picker implementation so if this doesn't work we'll probably need a new issue for the new picker

Comment: OK. As far as I can see the resolution for the old Picker does not work for the Picker which uses Spinner3D. I filed an issue: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3058